# Flutter Errors: Undefined name "context"

Tags: flutter

I receive some errors when I try to push my flutter page from neighbourhoodList to individual neighbourhoods (e.g. neighbourhoodlist_admirality).

In my neighbourhoodlist, I would like to navigate to the individual neighbourhood pages when the user has clicked on the relevant neighbourhood. As I have not build the individual neighbourhood pages yet, I have linked them to an example page i.e. NeighbourhoodAdmirality.

This is my code for the neighbourhoodlist page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'indv_neighbourhoods/neighbourhoodlist_admirality.dart';

class NeighbourhoodList extends StatefulWidget {
  NeighbourhoodList({ this.name = "name"});
  final String name;

  @override
  _NeighbourhoodListState createState() => _NeighbourhoodListState();
}

class _NeighbourhoodListState extends State<NeighbourhoodList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Neighbourhoods',
        ),
      ),
      body: _buildListView(context),
    );
  }

  ListView _buildListView(BuildContext context){
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: allNeighbourhoods.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext content, int index) {
          NeighbourhoodList neighbourhoodlist = allNeighbourhoods[index];
          return NeighbourhoodListTile(neighbourhoodlist);
        });
  }
}

class NeighbourhoodListTile extends ListTile {
  NeighbourhoodListTile(NeighbourhoodList neighbourhoodlist)
      : super(
          title: Text(neighbourhoodlist.name),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(
              context, 
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NeighbourhoodAdmiralty(neigh1)),
              );
          }
        );
}

List<NeighbourhoodList> allNeighbourhoods = [
  NeighbourhoodList(name: 'Admiralty'),
  NeighbourhoodList(name: 'Aljunied'),
  NeighbourhoodList(name: 'Ang Mo Kio'),

];
```

This is my code for an example page that I want to direct my neighbourhoodlist to when each individual neighbourhood is directed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NeighbourhoodAdmiralty extends StatefulWidget {
  final String neigh1;
  NeighbourhoodAdmiralty(this.neigh1);

  @override
  _NeighbourhoodAdmiraltyState createState() => _NeighbourhoodAdmiraltyState();
}

class _NeighbourhoodAdmiraltyState extends State<NeighbourhoodAdmiralty> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Admiralty"),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text('This is the individual neighbourhood page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As I am still a beginner, I am facing some errors and have a few questions on these:

Error 1 on neighbourhoodlist.dart: "Undefined name 'context'" under Navigator.push --> not sure why this happens as I have already passed the BuildContext in my methods above

Error 2 on neighbourhoodlist.dart: "Undefined name 'neigh1'" under Navigator.push --> I would like to redirect the neighbourhoodlist.dart page to the individual neighbourhood sheets but I'm not sure what I pass here, I have tried 'neigh1' (my variable in neighbourhoodlist_admirality), 'name' - the variable in NeighbourhoodList, and 'index' 0 the variable inNeighbourhoodListState but none of them seem to work so far.

Appreciate all your help in resolving this and thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```dart
class NeighbourhoodListTile extends ListTile {
  NeighbourhoodListTile(NeighbourhoodList neighbourhoodlist)
      : super(
          title: Text(neighbourhoodlist.name),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NeighbourhoodAdmiralty(neigh1)));
          }
        );
}
```

you can't access `context` in `onTap` because Flutter hasn't yet provided one to you in this point. If you need the `context`, use a StatelessWidget instead, where you can access it in the `build` method:

```dart
class NeighbourhoodListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final NeighbourhoodList neighbourhoodlist;

  const NeighbourhoodListTile(this.neighbourhoodlist);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //  Here's your context ^^^^^^^
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(neighbourhoodlist.name),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => NeighbourhoodAdmiralty(neigh1)));
      }
    );
  }
}
```

---

As to your second error, there is also no `neigh1` variable at this point. I don't know what your logic is, but I think you want to replace it with `neighbourhoodlist.name`:

```dart
class NeighbourhoodListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final NeighbourhoodList neighbourhoodlist;

  const NeighbourhoodListTile(this.neighbourhoodlist);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(neighbourhoodlist.name),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => NeighbourhoodAdmiralty(neighbourhoodlist.name)));
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Enzo, this solves my first error! Would you happen to know how to resolve the red swiggly line below neigh1 please?

Comment: @EleanorTay I've updated my answer, see if this solves your problem!

Comment: Hi @enzo, this is exactly what I need, thanks so much!